# EmberJS on="submit" and on="enter" gets fired by mouse click instead of enter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to submit the input value when pressing enter.

```
<input value={{company.name}} {{action 'save' company.id company.name}} on="enter">
```

Here, the save action fires when I click the input field. And the save action does not get fired when clicking enter.

I have also tried with on='submit' with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the input inside a form? because you can do something like

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8"  {{action "postMessage" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type='text' class="form-control" autofocus="true" valueBinding="content" autocomplete="off"}}
</form>
```

and define the `postMessage` in the `actions` array of your component